# not choosing a random item every time

Tags: java, arraylist, random, actionlistener

so I I'm trying to make a program where, when I click my Skate Or dice button, each label(representing a dice) changes to a random element from the corresponding list It belongs to. but so far when I click the button, the labels don't change to a random element, it gives me the same one each time I click it. I tested the output by printing it to the system when I click the button, and surly I get the same 4 answers eachtime. I would like some help figuring out why it chooses the same elements from each list repeatedly instead of different ones every time.

this is my main class

```
package skateordicegui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SKFrame extends SkateDice  {

public JFrame jf;

public JPanel jp;

static public JButton sod = new JButton("SKATE OR DICE!!");

static public JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Stance");
static public JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Turn");
static public JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Flip");
static public JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Spin");

public SKFrame() {
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setSize((d.width / 2), (d.height / 2)); 
    jf.setLocation((d.width / 2 - d.width / 4 ), (d.height / 2 - d.height / 4));
    jf.setMinimumSize(jf.getSize());
    jf.setResizable(true);
    jf.pack();
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    l1.setBounds(110, 150, 100, 40);
    l2.setBounds(230, 150, 100, 40);
    l3.setBounds(350, 150, 100,40);
    l4.setBounds(470, 150, 100,40);

    sod.setLocation(140, 20);
    sod.setSize(300, 100);

    jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    jp.setSize(jf.getWidth(), jf.getHeight() / 2);

    jp.add(l1);
    jp.add(l2);
    jp.add(l3);
    jp.add(l4);
    jp.add(sod);

    jf.add(jp);
    sod.addActionListener(action);
}

public ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == sod) {
        System.out.println(SkateDice.getStance());
        System.out.println(SkateDice.getTurn());
        System.out.println(SkateDice.getFlip());
        System.out.println(SkateDice.getSpin());

        l1.setText(SkateDice.getStance());
        l2.setText(SkateDice.getTurn());
        l3.setText(SkateDice.getFlip());
        l4.setText(SkateDice.getSpin());
        } else
            System.out.println("no swag");
    }
};



public static void main(String[] args) {


    SKFrame skf = new SKFrame();

}

}
```

and this is my SkateDice class

```
package skateordicegui;

import java.util.Random;

public class SkateDice  {

static Random r = new Random();

// First time dealing with arrays 
//this is the easy way (kinda like python)

static String[] d1 = {"Kickflip", "Kickflip", "Kickflip", "Heelflip", "Heelflip","Heelflip", "Shuv", "3 Shuv", "Shuv", "3 Shuv", "X", "Skate Or Dice"};
static String[] d2 = {"180", "180", "180", "360", "360", "360", "X", "Skate Or Dice"};
//OR
static String d3[] = {"FS", "FS", "BS", "BS", "FS", "BS", "X", "Skate Or Dice"};
static String d4[] = {"Regular", "Regular", "Regular", "Switch", "Switch", "Switch", "Nollie", "Nollie", "Nollie", "Fakie", "Fakie", "Fakie", "X", "Skate Or Dice"};

public static int r1 = r.nextInt(d1.length);
public static int r2 = r.nextInt(d2.length);
public static int r3 = r.nextInt(d3.length);
public static int r4 = r.nextInt(d4.length);

public static String flip = d1[r1];
public static String spin = d2[r2];
public static String turn = d3[r3];
public static String stance = d4[r4];


static public String getFlip() {
    return flip;
}

static public String getSpin() {
    return spin;
}

static public String getTurn() {
    return turn;
}

static public String getStance() {
    return stance;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call your getters, they simply return the values for flip, spin, turn and stance as expected. If you need them to change values each time you call them, you should implement something as:

```
static public String getFlip() {
    // generates a new random number
    r1 = r.nextInt(d1.length); 

    // set a new value to flip
    flip = d1[r1];

    // return the value
    return flip;               
}
```

Repeat this logic to the other getters and your program should work.